# Elementary approximations to $\zeta(s)?$

Tags: calculus, approximation, riemann-zeta, approximation-theory

What are the best approximations in terms of elementary functions of one real variable for:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s},$$ for $Re(s)>1?$

There is not an elementary function that equals $\zeta(s)$ so which one does best?

Comment: It's a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^s}dx = \frac{1}{s-1}.$  By [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) and [Euler MacLaurin Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), you can get good approximations.  See also any analytic number theory text.

Comment: I mean a curve of best fit for the zeta function

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the techniques I've mentioned do give you arbitrarily good approximations.